# How can I add time values in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, time

I want to add time values, e.g. 2:00 + 3:00 = 5:00.

How can I do that in ASP.NET using C#?

Answer (score 5):

With `TimeSpan`

```
TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
TimeSpan b = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0);
TimeSpan c = a + b;
```

Comment: Just thought it might be worth adding that there is nothing special here for ASP.NET, this is just standard C#

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at TimeSpan.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structures.  Using these types you can pretty easily perform most Date/Time operations.

Specifically look at these methods:

- [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e.aspx): Get extract Date/Time information from a string
- [TimeSpan.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx)
- [DateTime.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx)

A simple example would be:

```
public TimeSpan? AddTime(string time1, string time2)
{
    TimeSpan ts1;
    TimeSpan ts2;

    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(time1, out ts1) &&
        TimeSpan.TryParse(time2, out ts2))
    {
        return ts1.Add(ts2);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx

Answer (score -3):

```
TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(2,0,0);
TimeSpan b = new TimeSpan(3,0,0);
TimeSpan c = a.Add(b);
```

Comment: Way to copy somebody's answer.  AND you did not even format it!  That is pointless.

Comment: Josh, thanks for pointing this out. I much appreciate your comment!